# Error 'not convenient group definition' MFA analysis FactoMineR

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to perform an MFA using FactoMineR. My dataset consists of 25 variables that were measured for 6 products. This measurement was performed in 3 groups of subjects. I would like to perform an MFA including the 3 blocks (corresponding to the 3 subject groups), so that I see if the 3 subject groups responded comparable for the 6 products. At the moment I have the following but get an error:

```
> Model <- MFA(Datacomparegroups, group=c(rep(25,3)), type=c(rep("c",3)),
              ncp=5, name.group=c("young","normosmic","hyposmic"))
Error in MFA(Datacomparegroups, group = c(rep(25, 3)), type = c(rep("c",  : 
  not convenient group definition
```

Anyone an idea what I should change to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the number of columns of Datacomparegroups is not equal to 3. Change this to solve this error.